# Apache failed to redirect user agent to Rendertron

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, user-agent, rendertron

I deploy a single page application in apache and looking for using rendertron to render a static page for the user agent, but seems the apache failed to redirect the user agent to the specific rendertron. Rendertron is working as well as the proxy_http_module and rewrite_module were already enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot|googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|SkypeUriPreview|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\0.|developers.google.com/+/web/snippet|slackbot|vkshare|redditbot|applebot|whatsapp|TelegramBot|w3c_validator|rsiteauditor|sitecheckerbotcrawler|seositecheckup|seobilitybot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://x.x.x.x:3000/render/https://exmaple.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Where exactly are you putting this rule? What happens exactly? Does a "redirect" (not a proxy request) work? Your regex is "unusual". You have `bot` as the first alternation pattern, but this makes all the other "bot" checks that follow redundant (eg. `googlebot`, `bingbot`, `twitterbot`, `rogerbot`, etc. are all matched by `bot`). (Btw, it should be `Googlebot`, not `googlebot` - you are performing a case-sensitive match.)

Comment: I didn't realize that it is sensitive for big letter and small letter, i just change it carefully and now working, thank you for the tips.

Comment: Use the `NC` flag for a case-insensitive match.